# How to get Json array formatting on Spring boot Application in desired format

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im trying to generate Json response in spring boot in certain format & order as below, and got stuck at this level, any help would be appreciated for to get it expected format as im very new to spring boot.

**What i have developed so far and its output:**

```
{
"ok": true,
"enterprise": [
{
"name": "Man",
"city": "NYC"
}
],
"teams": [
{
"name": "Peter0",
"city": "London"
}
]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
"ok": true,
"enterprise": {
            "name": "Man",
            "city": "NYC"
            icon: {
                "image": "www.google.com"
                "default": true
                }
            },
"teams": [
        {
        "name": "Peter0",
        "city": "London"
        icon: {
                "image": "www.google.com"
                "default": true
                }
                 enterprise_id": "myID_enterprise",
                "enterprise_name": "myName_enterprise",
                "created": 1567585622
        }
]
}
```

**Below is my `UserList` class**

```
public class UserList { 
    private boolean ok=true; 
    private List<User> enterprise = new ArrayList<>(); 
    private List<User> teams = new ArrayList<>(); 

    { 
    enterprise.add(new User("Man","NYC")); 
    } 
    }
```

**Codes are attached as screenshot**

Comment: ` public class UserList {

    private boolean ok=true;
    private  List<User> enterprise = new ArrayList<>();
    private  List<User> teams = new ArrayList<>();

     {
        enterprise.add(new User("Man","NYC"));
    }

   //getters & setters here
}`

Comment: Why are you creating a list of enterprise?

Comment: i was just trying that way to get it in desired output. better suggestion are welcomed

Comment: Hi did it work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `list of Users` as an enterprise when the `UserList` class is instantiated. On Instantiation you are adding the `User` to the list. There are 2 changes which you have to do.

1. Change the `List` of `users` as `enterprise` and keep it as a `single` `enterprise user`.
2. In your instance initialization block remove the `enterprise.add` and just create a `enterprise user`.

Code Spinet below:

```
public class UserList { 
    private boolean ok=true; 
    private User enterprise = null; 
    private List<User> teams = new ArrayList<>(); 

    { 
    enterprise=new User("Man","NYC"); 
    Icon icon = new Icon("www.google.com",true);
    enterprise.setIcon(icon);
    } 
 }
```

Comment: it solved my enterprise part and thanks for that, how do i get that "icon" part inside the enterprise?

Comment: lets assume i have "icon" class  just like user class

Comment: Your icon class should be a part of the user class

Comment: i created Icon class inside user class and instantiated in the userList class just like for enterperise, but the output comes outside the enterprise brackers {}.

```    private boolean ok=true;
    private  User enterprise = null;
    private User.Icons icon = null;
    private  List<User> teams = new ArrayList<>();

    {
        enterprise = new User("Man","NY");
        icon = new User.Icons("www.google.com",true);
    }```

Comment: Anyone can help me here?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked  i used composition method for icon class in enterprise and i moved icon class from subclass of enterprise to new class as best practice.